# Is the residue field an extension of rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, field-theory

Take a (commutative unitary) ring $R$ and choose a maximal ideal $m\subset R$. My teacher defined the residue field at $m$ as $R_m/mR_m$, where $R_m$ is the localization of $R$ at $m$. First question: is this ring isomorphic to $R/m$? (It seems to me that it is of course).

My second question is: is the residue field at $m$ an extension of $R$? It seems to me that it isn't, because the map from $R$ to $R/m$ is unique and is not an inclusion, since has $m\neq 0$ as kernel. Thanks for clearing my ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ of $R$, the residue field at $\mathfrak{p}$ is defined to be $R_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}$, which one can show is equivalently the quotient field $Q(R/\mathfrak{p})$ of the integral domain $R/\mathfrak{p}$.  In the case where $\mathfrak{p}$ is maximal, then, the residue field of $R$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ is the quotient field of the field $R/\mathfrak{p}$, which is just $R/\mathfrak{p}$.  Thus, defining the notion for prime ideals instead of just maximal ideals is a bit more illuminating.

If $\mathfrak{p}$ is a nonzero prime ideal, then some nonzero elements of $\mathfrak{p}$ are killed, or set to $0$, in $R/\mathfrak{p}$, and thus they remain zero in the reside field.  Thus, the only residue field that can be an extension of the ring $R$ (as an $R$-alegbra) is for the ideal $(0)$, which is prime if and only if $R$ is an integral domain, in which case the given residue field is the quotient field of $R$.

In general, the residue field of $R$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ should be thought of as an $R$-algebra, in that there is a canonical ring homomorphism $$R \longrightarrow R/\mathfrak{p} \longrightarrow Q(R/\mathfrak{p}),$$ or, equivalently, the map above can be thought of as the ring homomorphism
$$R \longrightarrow R_{\mathfrak{p}} \longrightarrow R_{\mathfrak{p}}/\mathfrak{p}R_{\mathfrak{p}}.$$   In a way, the first ring homomorphism is easier to define, since its definition doesn't require localization, so I prefer to define the residue field of $R$ at $\mathfrak{p}$ to be the quotient field of the integral domain $R/\mathfrak{p}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:** "My teacher defined the residue field at m as Rm/mRm, where Rm is the localization of R at m. First question: is this ring isomorphic to R/m? (It seems to me that it is of course)."

**Answer:** Yes, this is true.You localize the exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathfrak{m} \rightarrow R \rightarrow R/\mathfrak{m} \rightarrow 0$ at $\mathfrak{m}$ and since $R/\mathfrak{m}$ is a field you get isomorphisms

$$R/\mathfrak{m} \cong (R/\mathfrak{m})_{\mathfrak{m}} \cong R_{\mathfrak{m}}/\mathfrak{m}R_{\mathfrak{m}}.$$

Comment: Thank you that's surely how the teacher wants us to prove it